# change picker value based on another picker values

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I am using two UIPickerView. Based on first, I need change values in another picker view.

Any idea how to get this done?

Note: I am using [CCPickerView](https://github.com/cbpowell/CPPickerView).

Comment: Please concise it i can't understand it.

Comment: Isn't is same as UIPickerView, where you use delegates titleForRow and didSelectRow?

Comment: You can reload data after selecting data from First UIPicker View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've done same thing in my project., here is the solution..

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInPickerView:(CPPickerView *)pickerView
{
   if (pickerView.tag == 110)
   {
      return [picker_1_ary count];
   }
   else
   {
      return [picker_2_ary count];
   }
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(CPPickerView *)pickerView titleForItem:(NSInteger)item
{
    if (thePickerView.tag == 110)
       return [picker_1_ary objectAtIndex:item];
    else
       return [picker_2_ary objectAtIndex:item];
}


- (void)pickerView:(CPPickerView *)pickerView didSelectItem:(NSInteger)item
{
   if (pickerView.tag == 110)
   {
       [picker_2 reloadAllComponents];
   }
   else
   {
       NSString *value = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@" , [picker_2_ary objectAtIndex:item]];
       NSLog(@"Selected value ::: %@", value);
   }
}
```

hope it helps., Thank you..

Comment: I am getting error as `[CPPickerView reloadAllComponents]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a202e0` and then getting BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 2):

Update the array which is used to populate the 2nd picker inside this method

```
 - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
      if(pickerView == picker1)
      {
        // Update the array
        pickerValuesArray2 = ...;
      }

    }
```

Comment: I am using CCPickerView, where I don't have this method,

Comment: what about this delegate??..
- (void)pickerView:(CPPickerView *)pickerView didSelectItem:(NSInteger)item
{
    
}

Comment: Also dont forget to reload the 2 picker by [picker2 reloadAllComponents];